# Does anyone have any experience with skinnybytes.com?

Tags: thin-client, vmware-view, pcoip

I'm looking for a PoE zero client that will work with VMWare View (PCoIP). I was shown an all-in-one computer that operates on PoE power at http://shop.skinnybytes.com/185-PoE-Computer-AIO-Elite-PoE-185.htm. It looks great, but they're not very well known as far as I can tell. Has anyone had any experience with this company? I'd also be grateful for any other recommendations for all-in-one zero-clients or computers that will run on PoE.

Comment: Note this thing take 19V DC, 3.42A; not 802.3af.

Comment: If you look closer, a high-power 802.3at power injector and power splitter are provided.

Comment: 802.3at provides up to 57v@0.6A (35W), which isn't even close to 19v@3.42A (65W) this takes. Even if their unit will run off 57v PoE, 65W would take 1.15A, which is quite a lot more amperage than typical Cat5/6 can handle over any reasonable distance in 802.3af or 802.3at configurations (Cat5/6 is usually stranded 24 AWG, rated for 0.6A by the NEC). Their Hi-PoE, which may work with 802.3at loads, uses a proprietary 4 pair configuration, and is advertised to supply up to 60W. Looks like "Marketing" got a hold of those numbers...

Comment: Good enough for me. I'll stay away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the SkinnyBytes PoE-185 does run completely off of PoE power, or you can use the included AC adapter.  The AC adapter is rated for a maximum of 19V/3.42A (60W), which is overkill for this unit which only consumes under 40 watts.  This particular model sips just a bit too much power to receive power over typical 802.3at (30W), which is the reason for the PoE+ supply.  It can easily be powered over CAT5e/CAT6 at a distance of up-to 100m.

The slightly smaller 15.6" AIO is 802.3at compliant and consumes under 30W of power.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Cisco has announced two VXC (virtualization experience client) devices supporting VMware View (PCoIP). Check out video demos of VXC 2100 and VXC 2200 http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps11295/Products_Sub_Category_Home.html

Comment: I appreciate the link, but the main thing we're looking for is a monitor that can be powered via PoE.